# Runtime Permissions Dialog box not showing up in Android 9 and below

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions, runtime-permissions

The permission dialog does not show up on Android 9 and below. My code works fine on Android 11. i've tried `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` and `ActivityResultLauncher` but none of them work.

When it runs the line `permissionResultLauncher.launch()` my app crashes and it also crashes the emulator, such that i have to delete the Emulator and reinstall a new one, otherwise it won't show me anything on the screen.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 <application
   ...
 </application>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private long pressedTime;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> permissionResultLauncher;
    private boolean isRecordPermGranted = false;
    private boolean isWritePermGranted = false;
    private int totalCount;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private ImageButton imgbtnRecord, imgbtnList;
    private ImageView ivRestore;
    private TextView tvLoading, tvRecord;
    private boolean asyncTaskRunning;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        totalCount = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
        if(totalCount < 4){
            totalCount++;
            editor.putInt("counter", totalCount);
            editor.commit();
        }

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        asyncTaskRunning = false;
        imgbtnRecord = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnRecord);
        imgbtnList = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnList);
        tvLoading = findViewById(R.id.tvLoading);
        tvRecord = findViewById(R.id.tvRecord);
        ivRestore = findViewById(R.id.ivRestore);

        tvLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ivRestore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgbtnRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgbtnList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isRecordPermGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        isWritePermGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        permissionResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), new ActivityResultCallback<Map<String, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Map<String, Boolean> result) {
                if(result.get(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)!= null){
                    isRecordPermGranted = result.get(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
                    Log.d("3","-------------------------" + isRecordPermGranted);
                }
                if(result.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= null){
                    isWritePermGranted = result.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    Log.d("4","-------------------------" + isWritePermGranted);
                }

                if(isWritePermGranted == false || isRecordPermGranted == false){
                    if(totalCount <3){
                        finishAffinity();
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, PermissionActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        imgbtnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isRecordPermGranted == false){
                    requestPermission();

                }else{
                    openRecordingActivity();
                }


            }
        });

        imgbtnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(!isRecordPermGranted || !isWritePermGranted){
                     requestPermission();
                }else{
                    openRecordingsListActivity();
                }

            }
        });

    


    }
   

    public void openRecordingsListActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecordingsListActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openRecordingActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecordingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(pressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

```
    public void requestPermission(){

        List<String> permissionRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!isRecordPermGranted && !isWritePermGranted){
            permissionRequests.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            permissionRequests.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }else if(!isRecordPermGranted){
            permissionRequests.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }else if(!isWritePermGranted){
            permissionRequests.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        Log.d("permissionRequests list", permissionRequests.toString());
        if(!permissionRequests.isEmpty()){
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
               boolean shouldShowRationale = false;
               if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ){
                      shouldShowRationale = true;
                       Log.d("1","-------------------------");
               }
               if( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
                   shouldShowRationale = true;
                   Log.d("2","-------------------------");
               }
               if(shouldShowRationale){
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Needed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.d("5","-------------------------");
               }else{
                   permissionResultLauncher.launch(permissionRequests.toArray(new String[0]));
                   Log.d("6","-------------------------");
               }

            }else{
                Log.d("old permission ", permissionRequests.toArray(new String[permissionRequests.size()])+" " );
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,permissionRequests.toArray(new String[permissionRequests.size()]), 5);

           }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 5){
            for (int i =0; i< permissions.length; i++){
                if(permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) && grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    isRecordPermGranted = false;
                }
                if(permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    isWritePermGranted = false;
                }
            }
        }

       if(isWritePermGranted == false || isRecordPermGranted == false){
            Log.d("REQUEST PERMISSIONS RESULT", "onPermissionResult");
            if(totalCount <3){
                finishAffinity();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, PermissionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

When i use the statement  `if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO )`

then it runs the first part of the "OR" statement and shows one of the permission dialog but it never shows both, even with an "&&" or my current code in the `requestPermission()`

i've tried it without `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`, but it still doesn't work.
I've also added the permissions in the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: i think the dialog box is hidden behind the activity, because if i minimize the app, i can see the dialog box for a split second.

Comment: I tried this : `permissionResultLauncher.launch(permissionRequests.toArray(new String[0]));                                                                                                                               try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ... 
}`                                                                                                                                        
and it shows me the dialog box but when i allow one permission, it does not move to the next one, it just closes the dialog box.

Comment: I just tried using EasyPermissions library and the dialog box is still hidden, when i minimize the app and come back, it shows me the dialog box.